# Can not ssh into docker container centOS server

Tags: docker, ssh, centos

I am pretty new to Docker, and I am making a simple centOS docker image that can run ssh processes and can also authenticate using ssh keys.
However, when trying to run `ssh username@hostname`, I get a `ssh: connect to host hostname port 22: Connection refused`.

Confused, I tried to see if ssh is actually running by typing in `ssh service status` and I got the following error: `System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate. Failed to connect to bus: Host is down`

I tried running it with the privilege flag but it didn't do any good. Here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM centos:latest

RUN yum update -y && yum -y install openssh openssh-server openssh-clients sudo initscripts

# Generate keys
RUN ssh-keygen -q -N "" -t rsa -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
RUN ssh-keygen -q -N "" -t rsa -f /root/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN cp /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
EXPOSE 22
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Edited: Added `EXPOSE 22` to the end of my dockerfile. Still not working.

Also this is what I see when I `docker ps`.
[image]

Also my telnet status:
[image]

Comment: You probably want a virtual machine for this.  A Docker container typically wraps only a single process; it doesn't run system daemons like sshd, and it doesn't usually have "users" or "passwords".

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But my company requires me to be able to do this with Docker

Comment: Expose port 22 in Dockerfile have you tried it? Is telnet working?

Comment: Hi, I've added EXPOSE 22 in my Dockerfile and it still returns a refused to connect error when I type  ssh root@e7d6fe4af279.  Also my telnet is working I think, please check my updated question.

Comment: The error is because the image doesn't have `systemd` running. There exists [this `openssh-server` image](https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxserver/openssh-server), I [maintain a build as well](https://github.com/masseybradley/openssh-server) if that could help. You could also try rebasing your image on [`centos` with `systemd`](https://hub.docker.com/r/centos/systemd/). `sshd` doesn't need to run as a daemon (`man sshd`: `-D ... sshd will not detach and does not become a daemon`).

Comment: @masseyb lifesaver! Thank you so much! It works!

Answer (score 1):

```
FROM centos/systemd:latest

RUN yum update -y && yum -y install openssh openssh-server openssh-clients sudo initscripts

# Generate keys
RUN ssh-keygen -q -N "" -t rsa -f /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
RUN ssh-keygen -q -N "" -t rsa -f /root/.ssh/id_rsa
RUN cp /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
EXPOSE 22
```

As @masseyb suggested, I changed the docker image that I pulled to one that already has systemd running. After that everything is working well!

Comment: A note that I wouldn't `COPY` `authorized_keys` into the image, rather bind-mount the `authorized_keys` at runtime reason being that I would never use your image in my environment because if I (for whatever reason) omitted crushing the keys then I'd be giving you access which isn't what I'd want for a production server. It's a moot point if you do not intend on sharing the image but just saying.